# Why call func from protocol instead of struct

Tags: swift, option-type

```
protocol Readable {}

extension Readable {
    func text() -> String? {
        "in protocol"
    }
}

struct Book: Readable {
    func text() -> String {
        "in struct"
    }
}

let book: Book? = Book()

print(type(of: book?.text))
print(type(of: book!.text))

print(book?.text())
print(book!.text())
```

output is:

```
Optional<() -> String>
() -> String
Optional("in protocol")
in struct
```

sample code above.
Why two func is the same, but  print results are different

Anyone have idea？

I adjust this will always call from struct

[image]

Comment: The protocol extension is returning an Optional String? while the struct is retuning a String.

Comment: without a concrete type to go off of due to it being an optional the compiler tries to find anything "concrete" it can about the object. In this case that concrete, indisputable thing is that the `Book` type, though an optional in this case, it implements a protocol `Readable` that has the `text()` method you called. So it pulls from the protocol since it can't determine anything else

Comment: @ZohairAbbasHadi  book is define optional, even use  func text() -> String ， will also return optional String

Comment: What is the practical purpose of annotating an optional type and clearly initialize the **constant** with a non-optional value?

Comment: @vadian this is a simple version.

Comment: Wether or not you like how the compiler does type interference here the underlying problem is that the function in the Book struct has almost an identical signature to the one in the protocol extension and this causes the compiler to behave in a way you didn't expect and of equally importance this will most likely cause some confusion and lead to mistakes from developers using the Book type in their code. So change one of the signatures.

Answer (score 0):

You print `type` of `text()` method, so you get a signature.
Take a look at this documentation:

- https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html ("Function Types" chapter)
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/type(of:)

Two last print sentences show value produced by that function.

Answer (score 0):

The `Readable.text()` method is a *default implementation* for the protocol, meaning that it is implemented for a conforming object if it doesn't provide its own `text()` method.

Default implementations can also be a bit unpredictable. In this case, your `Book` object implements its own `text()` method, so the protocol's default implementation *should* not be called. However, in `print(book?.text())`, you are actually calling the method on an Optional *containing* the `Book` object. The optional does not provide its own `text()` implementation (even though the containing book object does), so the default implementation is called.

I believe default implementations also make your code less efficient (because it requires dynamic dispatching), so for these reasons and more I try to avoid them when I can.